# How to replace paths string in a file using sed in cygwin

Tags: bash

I have 2 variables

```
mypath=c:\tmp\silent-install
replace=c:/tmp/myapp
```

I tried this command but it does not replace the string in the file

```
sed -i "s#$mypath#$replace#" file.txt
```

Can you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `mypath` variable assignment has problem, because your string has backslash.

try this way:

```
mypath='c:\\tmp\\silent-install'
```

then your sed one-liner should work fine.

TEST:

```
kent$  mypath='c:\\tmp\\silent-install'

kent$  replace=c:/tmp/myapp

kent$  cat file
c:\tmp\silent-install

kent$  sed -i "s#$mypath#$replace#" file

kent$  cat file
c:/tmp/myapp
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your first variable to :

```
mypath='c:\\tmp\\silent-install'
```